# How to write mysql json_contains function's first parameter with path in ORM query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a query in `sqlalchemy` the original sql is

```
select * from my_table where JSON_CONTAINS( info->'$.user[*].id', '["bob", "tom"]','$');
```

Now I don't know how to write it in `ORM` format

I have tried this

```
session.query(my_table).filter(func.json_contains(my_table.info["user"]["*"]["id"],'["bob", "tom"]','$'))
```

but did not work

Comment: Note that *but did not work* is not a good problem description. Please tell us what should have happened, and give us the output you got instead (like the error message from MySQL). Some sample data and the expected output would be best.

Answer (score 3):

You also need to translate the `->` operator here. From the [MySQL reference documenation on JSON search fuctions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path):

> The `->` operator serves as an alias for the `JSON_EXTRACT()` function when used with two arguments, a column identifier on the left and a JSON path on the right that is evaluated against the JSON document (the column value).

SQLAlchemy 1.3 and up supports `JSON_EXTRACT()` natively, by using *item subscription*, so `columnname[expression]`. You need to pass in the *whole expression on the right-hand side* here, as a single string:

```
session.query(my_table).filter(
    func.json_contains(
        my_table.info["$user.*.id"], 
        '["bob", "tom"]',
        '$'
    )
)
```

The `my_table.info["$user.*.id"]` Python expression is then compiled to `JSON_EXTRACT(info, "$user.*.id")`, which is the equivalent of `info->"$user.*.id"`.

Comment: thanks a lot! json_extract function works but it should be JSON_EXTRACT(info, "$.user[*].id")   columnname[expression] will be complie to '$. "%s" ' % expression which will not work